# Easiest way to limit thread count in a loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, heroku, concurrency

Heroku apparently limits the number of threads and issues `ThreadError (can't create Thread (11))` errors when you reach the limit.

What's the easiest way to limit the number of threads to a defined limit, say, `N`?  Assume the loop looks like this:

```
beers.each do |aBeer|
   threads << Thread.new(aBeer) { |beer|
      drink(beer)
   }
end
threads.each { |aThread|  aThread.join }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use gem [ruby-thread](https://github.com/meh/ruby-thread), it's thread pool.  Install with `gem install thread`.

```
require 'thread/pool'
N = 4
pool = Thread.pool(N) # COUNT OF YOUR THREADS 

beers.each do |aBeer|
   pool.process {
     drink(aBeer)
   }
end

pool.shutdown
```

Comment: Partially answer the question, OP asked how to partition beers / thread with limit thread.

Comment: it's a limited thread. In pool, you specify the count of threads.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, Heroku limit with a fixed number of thread (256), and also by memory limit (512 or 1024 MB, depending of your choice).

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#dyno-memory

---

I would do something like that, because beers are equitably repartited between each thread.

```
thread_limit = 10 # Here you define your thread limit
beers_per_thread = beers.count / thread_limit # Number of beers / thread 
thread_pool = nil
beers.each_with_index.map {|beer, index| 
    if index % beers_per_thread == 0
        puts "New Thread Created at beer #{index}, hips.."
        thread_pool << thread
        thread = Thread.new
    end
    # Thread stuff
}

thread_pool.each do |thread|
    # process thread
end
```

Coupled with the Bigxiang thread_pool, I think it's perfect.

Comment: Funny enough, I had read that same bug report page you linked to.  However, your interpretation of it is incorrect--they were just saying that in the case being described, it was a memory limit likely being reached rather than a thread limit. They didn't make any claims about Heroku's thread count being unlimited.  In fact, it's limited to 256 threads: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#processes-threads